# Dealing with git clone error exceptions doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, gitlab

I have this script which clone project and fetch it's LFS objects from gitlab.com. The most of the script work just fine except the "exceptions" part. Some of my projects have broken LFS objects which causing the clone process and script to fail. I though the best way how to deal it it would be to create an exception for it. Unfortunately the exceptions doesn't work. The project is cloned  no matter if it fails or not. The error which normally occurs when a project with broken LFS object is cloned seems to be ignored when I run the clone command in within "try". I've never used exceptions, but it seems to me that the reason why it doesn't work is that the error occurs after the clone command is executed and not during the command execution.

```
import gitlab
import os
import git
from git import Repo
import time
import logging

token = os.environ['TOKEN']

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', private_token=token)
group = gl.groups.get(GROUP_ID) # Group_ID = Any gitlab.com group ID
all_projects = group.projects.list(include_subgroups=True, all=True)
length = len(all_projects)

backup_dir = "/mnt/storage/backup/gitlab-daily"

for each in all_projects:

    project_name = each.attributes['name']
    url = each.ssh_url_to_repo
    project_dir = f"{backup_dir}/{project_name}"
        
    # Get number of commits in the project
    project = gl.projects.get(each.id)
    gitlab_commits = project.commits.list()
    commits_length=len(gitlab_commits)

    # If the project already exists, pull changes. 
    if os.path.exists(project_dir):
        print(f"<{project_name}> already exists. Pulling changes...")
        os.chdir(project_dir)
        git.cmd.Git().pull()
        os.system('git lfs fetch --all > /dev/null')

    # If project doesn't exists and contains at least 1 commit, clone it, but only if the clone 
    # process will not exit with error.
    elif not os.path.exists(project_dir) and commits_length > 0:
        # Try to clone the projects
        try:
            Repo.clone_from(url, project_dir) # try to clone the project
        # If the the clone process returns error, save the error into log file and skip the rest 
        # of the loop.
        except git.GitCommandError:
            logging.basicConfig(filename=(f'{backup_dir}/errors'), format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y', level=logging.ERROR)
            logging.error(f'Project {project_name} contains most probably one or more broken LFS Files!')
            continue
        # If clone process doesn't exit with error continue with this:
        else:            
            print(f"<{project_name}> doesn't exist yet. Cloning...")
            os.system('git lfs fetch --all > /dev/null')
```

If I don't catch the error, this is what error traceback:

```
    <PROJECT_NAME> doesn't exist yet. Cloning...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/gitlab-daily-backup/./daily-backup.py", line 40, in <module>
    Repo.clone_from(url, project_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 1032, in clone_from
    return cls._clone(git, url, to_path, GitCmdObjectDB, progress, multi_options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 973, in _clone
    finalize_process(proc, stderr=stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/util.py", line 329, in finalize_process
    proc.wait(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 408, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(self.args, status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git clone -v git@gitlab.com:path/to/project.git /mnt/storage/backup/gitlab-daily/project_name
  stderr: 'Cloning into '/mnt/storage/backup/gitlab-daily/project_name'...
Downloading data/test_images.zip (23 MB)
Error downloading object: data/test_images.zip (3295f51): Smudge error: Error downloading data/test_images.zip (3295f516788842c0ffaf68dd9cb8874d1169fa74b4126087aefe9eab281b9856): [3295f516788842c0ffaf68dd9cb8874d1169fa74b4126087aefe9eab281b9856] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it: [404] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it

Errors logged to /mnt/storage/backup/gitlab-daily/project_name/.git/lfs/logs/20210201T223931.898981748.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: data/test_images.zip: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code? There are some definitions that are not defined. For example, what is the `Repo` object that you use?

Comment: @astrochun Of course. I updated the code.

Comment: If you don't catch the exception, what is the error traceback?

Comment: @aneroid I updated the post with the error.

Comment: I don’t understand your else clause. It will only be executed if the try clone_from succeeds, so why would you clone_from again in the else clause?

Comment: @eemz You're right. It should't be there. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Lib use of https way for clone but GitLab use of SSH .

command for https:

```
git clone https://GitLab.com/JohnFaillib/Rep.git
```

and SSH

```
git clone ssh://git@gitlub.com/<JohnFailLib/Repo.git
```

names are not true and use of and ssh://git@yourUserName/yourRepoName.git

Comment: I'm afraid this is not issue of how you choose to clone it. I clone it with SSH and it's working just fine. This issue is that it is not catching clone error properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says “warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.” So if your desired end state is that project_dir will not exist if this happens, you will have to actively delete it in the except clause.

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but the problem is that everything in "except" clause is never executed. Probably because "Clone succeeded". Checkout which fails after isn't checked, so the clone as whole is consider as successful, but in reality it isn't. A solution would be to have an option to check files integrity inside a repository, but I don't know if it even possible.

Comment: Sorry, but your OP says that without the try you get a stack trace that ends in “raise GitCommandError” and with the “except GitCommandError:” you do not get the stack trace. Therefore it seems to me that the except clause *does* execute. Have you tried putting “assert False” into it to prove yourself whether it is being run or not?